# Are all multivariate elementary functions $C^\infty$ on any open ball for which they are defined?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions, elementary-functions

Are all multivariate elementary functions $C^\infty$ on any open ball for which they are defined?

I believe they are, and can find no counterexample, but do not know how to prove this.  (All the [candidate counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863571/continuity-and-differentiability-of-elementary-functions) I found were on boundaries, not in open balls).

---

## Update

Please use [this definition of elementary functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118149/414550).

If not, what restrictions on the set of elementary functions make them all $C^\infty$?

Comment: What is your definition of an elementary function? Typically the absolute value is considered an elementary function and it is not even differentiable.

Comment: If you don't like the absolute value, look at the cubic root, which is also not differentiable (and which is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Can you include your definition of elementary functions? Also, it's a bit rude to completely change the question after somebody posted an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be odd. Then the $n$th root $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^{1/n}$ is an elementary function (it is the inverse of the polynomial map $x\mapsto x^n$) and it is not differentiable at the origin (and in particular it is not $C^\infty$). Here I used the definition of wikipedia which includes inverses of polynomial functions.

The absolute value is yet another elementary function ($\vert x \vert=\sqrt{ x^2}$) which is not differentiable and hence also not smooth.

**Added:** If we want a class of functions which are all smooth on their maximal domain, we can exclude the logarithm in the definition [What makes elementary functions elementary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118113/what-makes-elementary-functions-elementary/118149#118149) The problematic functions arise from the fractional powers, which disappear if we exclude the logarithm.